# VMware VSphere VM keeps getting ping and rdp unresponsive

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, rdp, ping

I'm experiencing a very odd behavior on a win8.1 VM I have. After a while, it is becoming ping and RDP unresponsive, however this is still up and running in vSphere.

To go around this issue, all I have to do is log into my vCenter server, locate the machine, open console and just get to the login screen. After this, the machine is again ping and RDP responsive from outside vSphere.

I have checked the logs and there are no errors that would indicate such behavior. I have also checked to see the system boot time and it didn't shut down or restart since I installed it.

I have also checked the network settings and connectivity and these are fine.

Do you guys have any other suggestions please?

Comment: What version of ESXi are you using?

Comment: ESXi version is 5.5.0

Comment: So not a version that supports Windows 8 then? It's only supported from 5.5u3.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. I have approx. 150 VMs with windows 8.1 on them and they are all running fine except this new one...

Comment: Well I'm only going off facts  - check this; https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software